# Manage Display page not displaying anymore

Tags: entities, users, display-suite

I set (or at least tried to) my user display page (admin/config/people/accounts/display) to use DS 1col on friday and part way through the request my computer crashed out (the server is running on the local machine too) and now I can't seem to access that page if I let it run forever I get:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/modules/field_ui/field_ui.admin.inc on line 145

I've tried to:

- Clear caches
- Run cron
- Disable and re-enable DS

Although I'm continuing to play with DS, I'm assuming whatever got corrupted is related to the field_ui module because of the error and it only seems to be affecting the manage display for the user account page; no other user account pages or manage display pages are affected.

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to reset that page to the default?

Answer (score 0):

after playing around in the database for awhile and trying things (I backed it up first) I found the problem in the field_group table by deleting all the default user groups I can now see and edit the manage display page for the account